# How do I calculate the race result?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to create a runner where user would be able to enter three racers and input the time for them, where the result will be displayed according to the fastest time on a textbox, so far I have done the coding but I am not sure why it's not working when I press the result button.

Here's my code for the race

```
Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click

        Dim mRunner1Time As String
        Dim mRunner2Time As String
        Dim mRunner3Time As String


        mRunner1Time = (Val(uiRunner1TimeTextBox.Text))
        mRunner2Time = (Val(uiRunner2TimeTextBox.Text))
        mRunner3Time = (Val(uiRnner3TimeTextBox.Text))

        If mRunner1Time < mRunner3Time And mRunner1Time < mRunner2Time And _
                mRunner2Time < mRunner3Time Then

            uiFirstTextBox = uiRuuner1TextBox
            uiSecondTextBox = uiRunner2TextBox
            uiThirdTextBox = uiRunner3TextBox

        ElseIf mRunner1Time < mRunner3Time And mRunner1Time < mRunner2Time And
            mRunner3Time < mRunner2Time Then

            uiFirstTextBox = uiRuuner1TextBox
            uiSecondTextBox = uiRunner3TextBox
            uiThirdTextBox = uiRunner2TextBox

        ElseIf mRunner2Time < mRunner1Time And mRunner2Time < mRunner3Time And
            mRunner1Time < mRunner3Time Then

            uiFirstTextBox = uiRunner2TextBox
            uiSecondTextBox = uiRuuner1TextBox
            uiThirdTextBox = uiRunner3TextBox

        ElseIf mRunner2Time < mRunner1Time And mRunner2Time < mRunner3Time And
            mRunner3Time < mRunner1Time Then

            uiFirstTextBox = uiRunner2TextBox
            uiSecondTextBox = uiRunner3TextBox
            uiThirdTextBox = uiRuuner1TextBox


        ElseIf mRunner3Time < mRunner1Time And mRunner3Time < mRunner2Time And
            mRunner1Time < mRunner2Time Then

            uiFirstTextBox = uiRunner3TextBox
            uiSecondTextBox = uiRuuner1TextBox
            uiThirdTextBox = uiRunner2TextBox

        ElseIf mRunner3Time < mRunner1Time And mRunner3Time < mRunner2Time And
            mRunner2Time < mRunner1Time Then

            uiFirstTextBox = uiRunner3TextBox
            uiSecondTextBox = uiRunner2TextBox
            uiThirdTextBox = uiRuuner1TextBox
        End If
        End Sub
```

Comment: Please read [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). By the way: Why don't you put the three values into an array and then apply the [sort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zfce6bw8.aspx) function?

Comment: It is the Text property of the TextBox that you are trying to change. The statements should be of the form `uiFirstTextBox.Text = uiRunner1TextBox.Text`

Comment: Thank You Guys, it worked perfectly, is there any way that I can save the content of the form?